# Pause javascript until a function has been executed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to learn how to write a chrome extension. However I don't have a lot of experience with asynchronous programming and it is causing me problems.

```
chrome.windows.create(newWindow, function(t){myArray.push(t);});
// When I call myArray next it has not yet updated.
```

How would I work around this problem?

I have a few ideas

Put in a while loop:

```
int tempLength = myArray.length;
chrome.windows.create(newWindow, function(t){myArray.push(t);});
While (tempLength = myArray.length)
{
    //nothing
}
// call myArray
```

or add a 10 millisecond delay after chrome.windows.create

What would work best? is there a build in function to handle this situation?

Comment: The loop will never exit. As explained in your previous question, the window creation doesn't take place until the browser returns to the main event loop.

Comment: the code doesn't look very javascripty

Comment: Anything that depends on the window creation should be in the callback function. You were already told this in the other question.

Comment: Also, the loop condition uses `=` instead of `==` or `===`, which is an assignment. This will always be true, no matter what the array does.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make your use of myArray inside the callback:

```
chrome.windows.create(
    newWindow,
    function(t)
    {
        myArray.push(t);

        //Do your length check here
        if ( myArray.length === completeLength ) doMyAction( myArray );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the delay functionality for the execution. I have used the same in such condition in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend against using an interval to poll for a new item. Make it a part of the callback.

```
var myArray = [];
chrome.windows.create(newWindow,
  function(t){
    myArray.push(t);
    processNewItem(t);
  });

// Do not continue code execution at this point. Let the callback initiate the processing.


function processNewItem(t){
  //do whatever in here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

var t=setTimeout(function(){alert("10 minutes Completed")},10000)